# How do I make my image zoom fit within the new boundaries?

Tags: html, jquery, css

So far with this code I've managed to make the zoom plugin bigger, but I can't get the image to fit within the zoom. How do I make everything bigger and fit within the boundaries with the zoom still zooming into the image?

```
.zoomer {height: 1000px; width: 1500px;overflow: hidden;}

.ts-image-zoomer-container .ts-image-zoomer-viewer .zoomer { 
 Height: 1000px;
 Width: 1000px;
 Overflow: hidden;
 }


.zoomer {height: 1000px;width: 1500px;overflow: hidden;}

.ts-image-zoomer-container .ts-image-zoomer-viewer .zoomer { 
 Height: 1000px;
 Width: 1500px;
 Overflow: auto;
 } 

.ts-image-zoomer-holder {
Height: auto;
max-width: 1500px;}

.zoomer-image {height: 1000px; width: 1500px; overflow: hidden;}

.edgtf-portfolio-content{height: 1000px; width: 1500px; overflow: hidden;}
```

https://landofbeasts.com/portfolio-item/map-of-irulias/

Comment: Please share all your HTML, jQuery, and/or Javascript. Maybe this will help? https://jsfiddle.net/Taqi_Shah/0zshgg1a/

Comment: It's not fully working cause now I can't add text or other options.